# SitecoreFieldImageMapper still returns null instead of Empty Image in Glass mapper v.4.0.9.60

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2, glass-mapper, sitecore-mvc

We have upgraded to Glass mapper latest version 4.0.9.60 from v3 and after that we started getting null reference errors with RenderImage as it returns null instead of Empty Image. We have found out that this issue was fixed with ID#177 Glass mapper version v.4.0.4.53.

We have tried installing v.4.0.4.53 and reflected the Glass.Mapper.Sc dll but we didn't find the ID#177 fixes related to adding ReturnEmtpyImage field in Config and updating GetField() method of SitecoreFieldImageMapper.cs.

Please help or advise if we are missing something here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see this documentation: 
http://www.glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Documentation/EmptyImages

Comment: The link is not valid anymore, Can you please provide the new link?